# Is there a way to Automate Nunit Test from a Loaded Visual Studio Project(Test are written in Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I want to automate Selenium Webdriver Tests I have moved from Visual Studio to a VM with only Nunit on it. I would like to Run these tests daily preferably before i come into work using Task Scheduler. I can not use any third party tools. Is this possible if so how do i set this up? I have checked Nunit Documentation and Google there is on information on this.

Comment: This is very unclear. What exactly do your tests look like? Show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run selenium test with NUnit console and just calling the respective `dll`. See [this](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4.8) for command line options

**EDIT: **
Download NUnit Runner [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download). Set the path of the executable to the system path. [This](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=installation&r=2.6.3) will get you started with installation and, then create a basic batch file with following command

```
:: Nunit can be set to system path or simply calling the executable and call the dll with /run switch
NUnit/run "C:\selenium\bin\selenium.Tests.dll"
```

Then, schedule a basic windows task with scheduler. See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)
*you also have to make sure the assembly was build properly*

Comment: Saifur how do you setup the command line options do you add an assembly and place the code into the assembly?

Comment: See edit and let me know if something unclear and if that's what you wanted

Comment: If this answer you question fully please upvote me as well. That will encourage me to be on top of these :)